# Using Regex with reference to the accumulating state array to conditionally trigger actions in redux react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, redux, react-redux

I am building a simple calculator with React-Redux.
The idea is to calculate the result by eval() the string of expression from the input. I would like to prevent users from entering multiple decimals (".") for the same group of numbers by removing the duplicated "." through a "backspace". However, I'm struggling to get it working after hours of attempts. Below are the relevant codes...

```
=== Actions

const setInput = val => {
return {
    type: SET_INPUT,
    input: val
    };
};
const bkSpace = () => {
return {
    type: BK_SPACE
    };
};

=== Reducer
const CalReducer = ( state = defaultState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INPUT:
        return {
            ...state,
            input: action.input,
            expression: [...state.expression.slice(0), 
                action.input.replace("×", "*").replace("÷", "/")]
                .join("").replace(space, "")
        };
    case BK_SPACE:
        return {
            ...state,
            expression: [...state.expression.slice(0, state.expression.length-1)].join("")
        };
    default: return state;
    };
};

=== React class component functions before render()
filter = (key) => {
    const {setInput, bkSpace, expression} = this.props
    switch (key) {
            case ".":
            setInput(key);
            if (/REGEX/g.test(expression) || expression[expression.length-1] === ".") {
                bkSpace();
                bkSpace(); //maybe?
                showMsg("You cannot contain two '.' in one numer."); 
                setTimeout(() => showMsg("0"), 1500);
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            setInput(key);
            break;
    };
};
```

Tried all the way I can think of, still can't avoid the decimal when there is the presence of another decimal before the digit(s), like preventing decimal input or instantly 'backspacing' it after a decimal is already being presented in a group of numbers after an operator.

```
123+1.12. 
        ^prevent
12.3+112.1
        ^allow
123.3.
     ^prevent
...etc, like a normal calculator but prevent syntax error
```

By using Regex, I cannot find a way to include(or exclude) the qualified number groups properly to perform desired actions when the state expression is growing along by accumulating the inputs and the function results will become a mess. (like backspacing 1 state late, allowing the presence of another decimal appears before backspacing where users can input other digits with this state gap to escape the restriction and allowing sth like 123.1.12 with /\d*[.]\d*[-+*/]/ or /\d*[.]\d[-+*/]*/ /\d*[.]\d*[-+*/]+|\d*[.]\d*/ etc. that doesn't allow decimal input after operators)
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if the line doesn't match this :

```
/^[-+/]*(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[-+/]+(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*)?[-+/]*$/
```

then it has 2 decimals within a segment between operators.

https://regex101.com/r/e52FVw/1

```
 ^ 
 [-+/]* 
 (?:
    (?:
       \d+ 
       (?: \. \d* )?
     | \. \d+ 
    )
    (?:
       [-+/]+ 
       (?:
          \d+ 
          (?: \. \d* )?
        | \. \d+ 
       )
    )*
    
 )?
 [-+/]* 
 $
```

Comment: Thx a lot! I made a little modification on the notation for operators [-+*/] should be including a multiply sign as well. Now I just need to figure out how to include it in my codes to get my functions working.